# Url Rewrite and dynamic url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a url rewrite role, but I need some help for you.

The format of url is:

http://www.mysite.com/category/state/city/pagenumber/page.aspx?a=1&b=2&c=3

Everything in the url is dynamic so We can have this by example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/house-rentals/tx/austin/1/default.aspx?a=1&b=2&c=3
http://www.mysite.com/house-sells/or/salem/1/default.aspx?a=10&b=20&c=30
http://www.mysite.com/season/az/phoenix/1/default.aspx?a=100&b=200&c=300
```

I could do the url without the variables parameters (a,b and c) passing the values of category, state, city and page by parameter but I need pass the other variables too and I can't do something like [...]page.aspx/1/2/3 because I'll use the querystring variables in my code behind.

Someone can help me?

Thanks.
Sorry about my english.

Comment: You haven't said what you want to rewrite the urls to, it's not clear enough to be able to help.